# isEqual statement type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm doing some comparisons in my app, and recently found a comparison type like this:

```
[[self.someString isEqual: @"one"] ? @"two" : @"one"];
```

what type of comparison is this considered? I tried to add another comparison but apparently it wasn't made for more than two or three.

Comment: Are you asking about the `isEqual` part, or the `foo ? bar : baz` part?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg, mostly the `foo ? bar : baz` portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to compare strings. You do this by typing `isEqualToString:`

What you are doing is seeing if your object is the same object equal to the string object you just `initialized`. (Which will never be true because it is not the same object. For one, it has a new memory location.)

You can override `isEqual:` in your subclasses to say when it is "`true`" by comparing it to whatever variable or series of variables you want.

Finally, the `"(if this is true) ? (Do this) : (otherwise do this)"` is called a ternary operator and is used quite frequently by me as it is a nice shorthand. It's function is just as described in the previous sentence.

So for your code to work as I think you intended you would write:

To print out in the log...

```
[self.someString isEqualToString: @"one"] ? NSLog(@"two") : NSLog(@"one");
```

To assign something...

```
[self.someString isEqualToString: @"one"] ? self.anotherString = @"two" : self.anotherString = @"one";
```

Comment: Another way of assignment, `self.anotherString = [self.someString isEqualToString: @"one"] ? @"two" : @"one";`

Comment: That's neat. Is there a way to compare more than two using this approach?

Comment: @R2D4 you can daisy-chain them together but I wouldn't recommend it. If you need to use more than 2 conditions or those two conditions are fairly verbose I would recommend using a switch or if/if-else statements.

Comment: As [my company's Objective-C style guide](https://github.com/Raizlabs/Raizlabs-Cocoa-Style) says about nesting ternary expressions, “Don't even think about it.” ;)

Comment: @Scott, thanks - any reason why it's not recommended?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg, hehe - that's funny :D - and awesome document! that is a nice resource, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @R2D4 it looks tacky and it's not easy to read. Can cause problems down the road.

Comment: Ternary statements are more difficult to read and easy to get wrong. Go for clarity.